# MATLAB: scan the row of a matrix and use values to search another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have matrix X and A where
X = [x1, y1, 1, 1; x2, y2, 1, 3; x3, y, 2, 4]
A = [1, 1, 0; 1, 3, 1; 1, 4, 2]

I want to:
1. scan the last two columns for every row in X (FYI, these two number combinations are unique)
2. find those values in the first two columns of A
3. get the value of the last column in that row of  A.

For example, for the first row of X, I get 1 and 1, so I find 1 and 1 for the first two columns in A (which appears to be the first row), so the number I want to get is 0.

I think I can do it using a loop and a "find" function if it were just one number I'm working with, but I'm new to matlab and have trouble with a combination of two numbers. I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ismember` function may be what you're looking for, along with the `()` and `:` operators to extract columns from an array.

```
% Map rows in X to rows in A
[tf,loc] = ismember(X(:,[3 4]), A(:,[1 2]), 'rows');
% Grab the corresponding value from A
rslt = A(loc, 3);
```

Now you have a logical vector `tf` that indicates for each row in X whether it was found in A, and `loc`, which holds the corresponding indexes in to the rows of A for the ones that matched. Then you use those indexes to index in to A to pull out the "value" or dependent variable columns. These are vectorized operations, so it'll be faster than doing it with loops and `find()`.

Read through the documentation for `ismember`, `unique`, `paren`, and the functions they reference to get more background on Matlab's functions for doing recordwise searching like this.